# Is there a way to expand key-values in resource properties or tags into their own columns in azure resource graph?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

I want to be able to expand the "dynamic" columns in Azure resource graph such that each key/value pair has its own column. Its something that would be nice for resource properties, and resource tags.
So for example this is what i currently get
[image]

But want to have something like, without hard coding in values like how i created that.
[image]

I saw something about `Evaluate unpack_bag()` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you provide the sample data in a datatable form and the unpack_bag query?

Comment: I don't think Azure Resource graph supports that function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Resource Graph supports a subset of KQL data types, scalar functions, scalar operators, and aggregation functions.

Specific tabular operators are supported by Resource Graph, and the `evaluate` operator isn't one of them as of today. So you might have to expand/project them individually until then. Find the complete list of supported KQL language elements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language#supported-kql-language-elements).